# javafx auto update table like IDM download

Tags: javafx

I wrote a download application on javafx. I have one table to display progress like IDM.

My table display data by an observable list (obList). I'm using a solution that i get all data from obList, edit data in last object of list and then i put all back to obList. But, it will be very slow if obList have big data

So, anyone can show me some other solutions to update it

Thank you very much

Comment: Why are you doing that? Why not just update the last element of the list?

Comment: Yes, @James_D, i don't know how to do like that, can you show me how to do?

Comment: `ObservableList<Something> tableData = table.getItems();` `Something lastItem = tableData.get(tableData.size()-1);` Then just change the `lastItem`. Obviously replace "Something" with whatever data type you declared for your table.

Comment: i do like that, but my tableview was not changed :(

Comment: Post an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org)